# System.out.print consumes too much memory when printing to console. Is it possible to reduce?

Tags: java, string, int

I have simple programm:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
            System.out.print(1);
        }
    }
}
```

And launched profiling. Here are the results:

[image]

I assume that memory grows because of this method calls:

```
public void print(int i) {
        write(String.valueOf(i));
    }
```

Is there a way to print **int** values in the console without memory drawdown?

On local machine I try add `if (i % 10000 == 0) System.gc();` to cycle and memory consumption evened out. But the system that checks the solution does not make a decision. I tried to change the values of the step but still does not pass either in memory(should work less than 20mb) or in time(<1sec)

EDIT I try this

```
    String str = "hz";
    for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_0000; i++) {
        System.out.print(str);
    }
```

[image]
But same result:

**EDIT2** if I write this code

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] bytes = "hz".getBytes();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_0000; i++) {
            System.out.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        }
    }
}
```

I have this

[image]

Therefore, I do not believe that Java is making its noises. They would be in both cases.

Comment: `String str = String.valueOf(i); for (...) { System.out.print(str); }`.

Comment: Does not help. Even if I print just `System.out.print()`. all the same on the mountain chart with a peak at ~40mb

Comment: If you still reach 40MB if you're printing *nothing*, there's not really very much else you can do. You can't print less than that.

Comment: this is a real task) sample task for the interview. Therefore, the solution should be.

Comment: Given an ordered array of 32-bit integers in non-decreasing order. It is required to remove from it all repetitions.

It is desirable to obtain a solution that does not read the input file entirely in memory, i.e., uses only a constant amount of memory in the process.

Input format
The first line of the input file contains a single number n, n ≤ 1000000.

The following n lines contain numbers — the elements of the array, one per line. Numbers are sorted by non-decreasing.

Output format
The output file must contain the following in ascending order unique elements of the input array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the `int` into characters without generating a new `String` each time you do it.  This could be done in a couple of ways:

- Write a custom "int to characters" method that converts to ASCII bytes in a `byte[]` (See @AndyTurner's example code).  Then write the `byte[]`.  And repeat.
- Use `ByteBuffer`, fill it directly using a custom "int to characters" converter method, and use a `Channel` to output the bytes when the buffer is full.  And repeat.

If done correctly, you should be able to output the numbers without generating any garbage ... other than your once-off buffers.

Note that `System.out` is a `PrintStream` wrapping a `BufferedOutputStream` wrapping a `FileOuputStream`.  And, when you output a `String` directly or indirectly using one of the `print` methods, that actually does through a `BufferedWriter` that is internal to the `PrintStream`.  It is complicated ... and apparently the `print(String)` method generates garbage somewhere in that complexity.

---

Concerning your EDIT 1: when you repeatedly print out a constant string, you are still apparently generating garbage.  I was surprised by this, but I guess it is happening in the `BufferedWriter`.

Concerning your EDIT 2: when you repeatedly write from a `byte[]`, the garbage generation all but disappears.  This confirms that at least one of my suggestions will work.

However, since you are monitoring the JVM with an external profile, your JVM is also running an *agent* that is periodically sending updates to your profiler.  That agent will most likely be generating a small amount of garbage.  And there could be other sources of garbage in the JVM; e.g. if you have JVM GC logging enabled.

Comment: The integer in the code is used as a counter and never printed. The code keeps printing the same string so it doesn't produce any garbage. Very miss-leading answer

Comment: The code is calling `print(1)` and that is converting `1` to a new `String` each time it is called.  It neither knows or cares that the it is repeatedly converting the same number.   I don't see why this is misleading.

Comment: quote from OP:
EDIT I try this

    String str = "hz";
    for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_0000; i++) {
        System.out.print(str);
    }
In this code there is no print of an integer and problem still persists. The solution is to set jvm memory usage params (See my answer)

Comment: To quote from my answer: "There may be other sources of garbage".   You seem to be implying that there is no way to output in Java without generating garbage.  What is your evidence for this?

Comment: @MichaelGantman another quote from OP: "should work less than 20mb".

Comment: @ Stephen C I can not agree. Or correct me. `byte[] bytes = "hz".getBytes();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_0000; i++) {
            System.out.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        }`  consumes almost constant memory capacity. if java gave noises - they would appear here

Comment: @ip696 - You are generating garbage in the profiling agent at a constant rate.

Comment: @Stephen C I do it in both cases. When I withdraw `System.out.print(str);` I have mountain chart but when `System.out.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length); }` - smooth chart  10mb. And I add eddit2 to question

Comment: This is I think supporting what I say, not contradicting it.  When you use a `byte[]` that you generate once, you are reducing the amount of garbage generated to a very low level.  But that that low level is coming from other things; i.e. the profiler agent.   It is recording stats about memory usage ... and quite possibly other things (depending on how you are running it, what monitoring you have enabled.)

Comment: But when I print the same line (I suppose it is cached) should there be a similar behavior? why not?

Comment: Try debugging what the `print(string)` call is doing.  It is probably more complicated than  you think.  Then compare it to `write(byte[], int int)`.

Comment: At any rate, one of my suggestions for minimizing the garbage generated was to use a fixed `byte[]` ... and your EDIT 2 seems to show that this will work!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have discovered that printing a `byte[]` keeps memory allocation within the required bounds, you can use this fact:

Allocate a byte array the length of the ASCII representation of `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (11  - the longest an int can be). Then you can fill the array backwards to convert a number `i`:

```
int p = buffer.length;
if (i == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
  buffer[--p] = (byte) ('0' - i % 10);
  i /= 10;
}
boolean neg = i < 0;
if (neg) i = -i;
do {
  buffer[--p] = (byte) ('0' + i % 10);
  i /= 10;
} while (i != 0);
if (neg) buffer[--p] = '-';
```

Then write this to your stream:

```
out.write(buffer, p, buffer.length - p);
```

You can reuse the same buffer to write as many numbers as you wish.

Answer (score -3):

The pattern of memory usage is typical for java. Your code is irrelevant. To control java memory usage you need to use some -X parameters for example "-Xms512m -Xmx512m" will set both minimum and maximum heap size to 512m. BTW in order to minimize the sow-like memory graph it would be recommended to set min and max size to the same value. Those params could be given to java on command line when you run your java for example:

```
java -Xms512m -Xmx512m myProgram
```

There are other ways as well. Here is one link where you can read more about it: [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs60/perform/JVMTuning.html). There are other params that control stacksize and some other things. The code itself if written without memory usage considerations may influence memory usage as well, but in your case its too trivial of a code to do anything. Most memory concerns are addressed by configuring jvm memory usage params